# code result not showing up when escaping special characters in img tag

Tags: html, escaping, special-characters

<img class="logo"src="../images/logo.png"alt="peg">

why is the image tag showing "special characters must be escaped" in the above code?
I tried using &lt and &gt but it does not function as code then?it worked as plain text which showed up in the browser instead of result of the code.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem but you should have spaces between attributes like this: `<img class="logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="peg">`

Comment: If you have `class="logo"src="../path"` maybe your editor thinks the double quote between *logo* and *src* is part of a longer string rather than terminating the string. It then thinks you need to escape the double quote??

Comment: the spaces!!!.as simple as that.Thankyou for the right correction.